# How to use an image deployed on cloud run for kubernetes deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I want to deploy an image from cloud run to kubernetes cluster. I have successfully built the docker image in `cloudbuild.yaml` file. Now the challenge is how to use the image in `deploy.yaml`

The task fails with errors indicating the the variables were not substituted as expected.

Here are the config excerpts:

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
//push image to container registry
    ....
    .......

  - id: "deploy container image to GKE"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy"
    args: [
    "--cluster", "${_CLUSTER_NAME}",
    "run",
    "--filename", "deployment.yaml",
    "--image", "us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/abc/abc-server-${_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE}:$COMMIT_SHA",
    "--location", "${_COMPUTE_ZONE}"
    ]
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
    ....
    ........
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: idr-server-k8ts-test
          image: us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/abc/abc-server-${_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE}:$COMMIT_SHA
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

*Vars defined in build trigger*

```
_CLUSTER_NAME
_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE
_COMPUTE_ZONE
```

I get the error:

`Error: failed to prepare deployment: failed to update container of objects: failed to parse reference from image "us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/abc/abc-server-${_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE}:$COMMIT_SHA": could not parse reference: us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/abc/abc-server-${_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE}:$COMMIT_SHA`

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to please update the status of question if any of below answer resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes doesn't understand any variables written in manifest files. Your image's name (`us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/abc/abc-server-${_DEPLOYMENT_TYPE}:$COMMIT_SHA`) contains environment variables. Plain manifests require constant/hardcoded values.

If you want to populate your manifests dynamically through environment variables, create a [helm chart](https://helm.sh/) and apply it in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Try once like with using the `""`

```
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy"
  args:
  - run
  - --filename=deployment.yaml
  - --image=harshmanvar/gdg-rajkot:$SHORT_SHA
  - --expose=80
  - --app=nodejs-hello-demo
  - --location=asia-east1-a
  - --cluster=cluster-1
```

**Extra option :**

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
substitutions:
    _CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE: us-central1-c  # default value
    _CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER: standard-cluster-1      # default value
steps:
- id: 'set test core image in yamls'
  name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash','-c','sed -i "s,TEST_IMAGE_NAME,gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA," deployment.yaml']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  args: ['apply', '-f', 'deployment.yaml']
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=${_CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE}'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=${_CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER}'
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
containers:
      - image: TEST_IMAGE_NAME
        name: test-image
        ports:
```

So cloud build will replace the `TEST_IMAGE_NAME` in **deployment.yaml** and updated file will get deployed to **GKE**.

You can find the example : https://github.com/harsh4870/basic-ci-cd-cloudbuild